# Как создать галерею на PHP?

Tags: php

Всем привет.

**Вопрос следующий - есть интернет магазин, в нее загружаются товары. Так же у Товаров есть несколько изображений**.

Вывод одного изображения не составит труда, я в таблицу записывают путь изображения и при выводе подставляю этот вывод. НО как сделать что бы была некая галерея изображения этого товара, например 2 или 3 изображения,? Как реализовывается такая штука? Тоже надо записывать пути этих изображений в таблицу???
СПАСИБО ЗА ПОМОЩЬ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добрый вечер. Да нужна таблица, и если у 1 товара несколько фото, то отдельная, т.к. связь получается 1:М

Т.е. первая таблица с товаром

```
id
name
params
price
```

и вторая с изображениями

```
id
id_goods
photo_path
```

Answer (score 3):

Есть разные варианты реализации. Самый простой: создайте вторую таблицу, в которой один столбец содержит номера записи из таблицы товаров, второй -- пути к файлам. 
Тип связи называется "один ко многим".